# How to add different color to nth-of-type

Tags: css, styled-components

I have a table whose rows I'm styling with `nth-of-type(even)`. Now I need to add a condition to override the row color only if the value is less than 0. I'm using styled components and my code looks like this

```
<StyledTableRow
      data={row}
      hover
      key={index}
      onClick={() => {
        rowClick && rowClick(row);
      }}
 >
      {headers.map(
        ({ column, label, transform }: { column: string; label: string; transform?: any }) 
       => (
          <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row" key={label}>
            <RowText link={column === 'email' || column === 'name'}>
              {transform ? transform(row) : row[column]}
            </RowText>
          </StyledTableCell>
        )
      )}
 </StyledTableRow>
```

and styled component is like this

```
const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow) <RowDataProps>`
/* background-color: ${({ theme, data }) => data.daysOut < 0 ? theme.colors.danger : 
   theme.colors.secondary}; */
   &:nth-of-type(even) {
      background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.secondary};
   }
`;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
    const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow) <RowDataProps>`
   :nth-of-type(even) {
 background-color: ${({ theme, data }) => data.daysOut < 0 ? theme.colors.danger : 
   theme.colors.secondary};
   }
 background-color: ${({ theme, data }) => data.daysOut < 0 ? theme.colors.danger : 
   initial};
    `;
```

Comment: I've already tried this. This will change the color of every second element to danger.

Comment: Ok, I edited my comment. Make sure to check your condition too with some console logs, maybe the problem doesn't come from the css.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Fantastic! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What is structure of data that is being passed as props? Unfortunately I can't comment hence posting it as answer..